# C# Regular Expression Conventional Commits Id and Description

Tags: c#, regex

I mad a really long a Regex for Conventional Commits in C#.
All it does is keep the format for conventional commits like -> type(scope)!: Description (id-123) and optional a \r\n with text.
How can I be sure after a \r\n does not follow a new feat: or fix: ?

```
^(?<type>(?:feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|build|chore))(?:\(\w+\))?(?:!)?:\s{1,2}(?<Description>(?:.+?))\s{0,2}(?:(?<id>\(#\w+-\d+\))|(?<id>\(#untracked\)))?(?:(?:\r\n)*(?:\w)*(?:\d)*(?:\s)*[^A-Za-z0-9]*)*$
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, (I have omitted the the named capture groups for now), the first part of the pattern matches for example `feat(1)!: a(#1-2)`

```
^(feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|build|chore)(?:\(\w+\))?!?:\s{1,2}(.+?)\s{0,2}(?:(\(#\w+-\d+\))|(>\(#untracked\)))?
```

The part after it with the newline, has only optional parts:

```
(?:(?:\r\n)*(?:\w)*(?:\d)*(?:\s)*[^A-Za-z0-9]*)*$
```

---

One option could be making only the last part optional leaded by a negative lookahead after matching a newline excluding all specified alternatives.

```
(?:\r?\n(?!feat|fix).+)?$
```

This part `.+` matches the whole line with  at least a single character other than a newline, and can be customized according to what it should specifically match.

The full pattern with the named capture groups could then look like:

```
^(?<type>feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|build|chore)(?:\(\w+\))?!?:\s{1,2}(?<Description>.+?)\s{0,2}(?:(?<id>\(#\w+-\d+\))|(?<id>\(#untracked\)))?(?:\r?\n(?!feat|fix).+)?$
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3ctype%3efeat%7cfix%7cdocs%7cstyle%7crefactor%7ctest%7cbuild%7cchore%29%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5cw%2b%5c%29%29%3f!%3f%3a%5cs%7b1%2c2%7d%28%3f%3cDescription%3e.%2b%3f%29%5cs%7b0%2c2%7d%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cid%3e%5c%28%23%5cw%2b-%5cd%2b%5c%29%29%7c%28%3f%3cid%3e%5c%28%23untracked%5c%29%29%29%3f%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!feat%7cfix%29.%2b%29%3f%24&i=feat%281%29!%3a+a%28%231-2%29%0d%0atest&o=m)

If you want multiple lines after that do not start with one of the alternatives:

```
^(?<type>feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|build|chore)(?:\(\w+\))?!?:\s{1,2}(?<Description>.+?)\s{0,2}(?:(?<id>\(#\w+-\d+\))|(?<id>\(#untracked\)))?(?<text>(?:\r?\n(?!feat|fix).+)*)
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3ctype%3efeat%7cfix%7cdocs%7cstyle%7crefactor%7ctest%7cbuild%7cchore%29%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5cw%2b%5c%29%29%3f!%3f%3a%5cs%7b1%2c2%7d%28%3f%3cDescription%3e.%2b%3f%29%5cs%7b0%2c2%7d%28%3f%3a%28%3f%3cid%3e%5c%28%23%5cw%2b-%5cd%2b%5c%29%29%7c%28%3f%3cid%3e%5c%28%23untracked%5c%29%29%29%3f%28%3f%3ctext%3e%28%3f%3a%5cr%3f%5cn%28%3f!feat%7cfix%29.%2b%29*%29&i=feat%281%29!%3a+a%28%231-2%29%0d%0atest%0d%0atesting+test%0d%0a%0d%0afeat%281%29!%3a+a%28%23untracked%29&o=m) *(click the table tab and see group **text**)*

**Note** that the pattern contains `\s` which by itself can also match a newline.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the Problem with this Regex inculding ignorecase and multiline:

```
^(?<type>(?:feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|build|chore))(?<scope>(?:\(\w+\)))?(?:!)?:\s{1}(?<description>(?:.+?))\s*(?:(?<id>\(#\w+-\d+\)\s*)|(?<id>\(#untracked\)\s*))?$
```

And in my Method:

```
var match = this.regex.Match(logMessage);
return match.Success && !match.NextMatch().Success;
```

But how can I prevent this? This should be false.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKPRz.jpg